# How to assign a click event to button passed in from parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a FileUploader which needs to trigger from outside the component via prop, i have been battling for hours and could not figure out.

```
export class App {
   let button = (<button>Click me please!</button>);
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="app">
            {button}

            <FileUploader trigger={button} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export class FileUploader {
  constructor(props) {
     this.trigger = props.trigger; // <button>Click me please!</button>

     // do something to attach an onclick trigger element to simulate a 
     // click to the file input
  }

  render() {
      return (
         <div className="file-uploader">
            <input type="file" style="display: none;">
            <div>
               // display the file image and some other additional file info
            </div>
         </div>
      );
  }
}
```

i wish that **this.trigger** will simulate a click to the **input**, which will open up a window to select files .. how can i do this? much appreciated

Comment: you have a parent component, which has a button, and child component which has a file-input? what you want to do is, trigger a click on file-input on button click yeah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a empty ref to `FileUploader` from the parent component, and we will assign that ref to the input-file, and when you click on the button you have the access to the input, so you can manually trigger click

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fileInput = React.createRef(); // Create a empty ref
  }

  openFileInput = () => {
    this.fileInput.current.click(); 
    // since we have access to the fileinput, we can trigger manual click
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.openFileInput}>
          open file browser in child component
        </button>
        .......
        <FileInput fileInputRef={this.fileInput} />
        // pass the empty ref to the file input so we can assign it to the input-file
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class FileInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="file-uploader">
        ....
        <input
          type="file"
          ref={this.props.fileInputRef} // assign the ref to the input
          style={{ display: "none" }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fe3ss3)

Comment: Wow ty, your answer is wonderful! however I am just now if its possible for FileInput component to attach click event somehow, so all the logic lives in that component. I am asking because we will have many many components that will be using FileUpload, and i want all these components that other devs are writing to do minimum work. I revised my question, if you are interested. Otherwise i will use your answer because it works great = )

Comment: Thank you, ok so you have a button in parentComponent, and you want to manually trigger a click on a file-input which is in childComponent, but this click logic should be in childComponent, is that right?

Comment: Yes that would be great. Because even though your method is very good and probably the right way to do in react, but i want to try to isolate all the click logic to inside of the FileUpload component. This way the components calling it would do minimum work, and only need pass in a button into the props.

Comment: Yes, correct, don't you think you can move the button to the `childComponent`, and if we click on it, we will manually trigger a click event on file-input?
Other vice you have to repeat button on every component

Comment: Unfortunately the button will have to be outside the component, because the component can be away from the button (ex. the uploading images can appear in a popup screen, on a side slider, anywhere)

Comment: @andyh0316 Then i'll do like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1dkbwy

Comment: Ill move button to another component, and onClick ill trigger a custom event, ill catch that event in fileInput, then ill trigger a click on the file input

Comment: And since file input is hidden, why can't you create a new component to the button and put the file-input in to that

Comment: Because evn tho the file input is hidden, theres images below that will be showing that is separate from component. If you look at twitter on desktop, you click on a trigger icon to bring up window to select images, once you select images, the images will display separately away from the icon.

Comment: @andyh0316 yeah that's right, So displaying the selected image, and the file-input is two independently working components, use teh file-input to gets select the file after selecting it, update the state, since the state gets update, show a image based on updated state on a different component

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example of how you can pass function to child component from parent and call them from child component.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Children extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPress = props.onPress;
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onPress} color="success">
          Child Click
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  fromParent = () => {
    alert("Called from children");
  };
  render() {
    return <Children onPress={this.fromParent} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```